# Regular Expression to find a string containing specific substring between two delimeters in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I need to extract a string with multiple variations in between two comma delimiters.

The known similarity of these string is that it contains "LED" in the line.

Possible variations include "W-LED", "OLED", "Edge LED (Local Dimming)", "Direct LED" but are not only limited to those.

I want to extract all the substrings in between the delimiter with the comma removed. The strings are in a column inside a data frame. Two example:

```
ori_col <- c(
  "Display: 27 in, VA, Viewing angles (H/V): 170  / 160, W-LED, 1920 x 1080 pixels",
  "Display: 21.5 in, VA, Edge LED (Local Dimming), 1920 x 1080 pixels"
)
df <- as.data.frame(ori_col)
```

What I want to extract

```
"W-LED"
"Edge LED (Local Dimming)"
```

So I plan to mutate a new column to extract the values from the original column using regex.

```
df %>% mutate(new_column = str_extract(ori_col, "regex"))
```

I figure it must use something like lookaheads and lookbehinds but have no idea how to write the in between regex.

```
df %>% mutate(new_column = str_extract(ori_col, "(?<=\\,)(what should I write here)(?=\\,)"))
```

This question is derived from my previously overcomplicated question [parsing to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653194/how-to-extract-specific-substring-with-multiple-variations-in-between-two-delimi) if you want to understand more.

Comment: Have you tried `(?<=\,).*?LED.*(?=\,)`?

Comment: another one `gsub(', *([^,]*LED[^,]*),|.', '\\1', x)`

Comment: I try using `df %>% mutate(new_column = str_extract(ori_col, "(?<=\\,).*?LED.*(?=\\,)"))` and it extract almost the entire string, only skipping the first substring before the first delimiter.

Comment: @rawr Your approach seems to work! Can you explain how it did not take the coma with it?

Comment: i put the commas outside of the parentheses, so it matches comma + any whitespace, then starts the capture until the next comma which is also outside of the capture group

Comment: @rawr I was surprised to see a regex OR with only one of the conditions having a capture class. Seems to work well in that the alternative matches anything else and then gets replaced by `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential, readable solution is using:

```r
library("tidyverse")
mutate(df, extracted_str = str_match(string = ori_col, 
                                     pattern = "(.*\\,)(.*LED.*)(\\,.*)")[,3])
```

## Notes

- In this context you will be always looking to extract **third** group that contains the *LED* word. In order to bring to the results as a single column we subset the results from `str_match` to `[,3]`.
- As [shown on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oPcDf8/1), the regex identifies the third group when encounters the `LED` word after a comma.
  [image: Regex explanation from regex101]
- To get an understanding of the components that are landed in each group remove the subset `[,3]` from the `str_match` results:

  ```
  mutate(df, extracted_str = str_match(string = ori_col, 
                                       pattern = "(.*\\,)(.*LED.*)(\\,.*)"))
  ```
- You can run `trimws` / `str_trim` to get remove white spaces from the results

  ```
  mutate(df, extracted_str = str_trim(str_match(string = ori_col, 
                                 pattern = "(.*\\,)(.*LED.*)(\\,.*)")[,3]))
  ```

Comment: It definitely works and is neat! But I have such a hard time understanding how it works. How do you identify this third group? In the regex101, the third group in the match information is not the string that we wanted. And the 'LED' containing string is not at the same place (one is after the 3rd comma, the other is after the second comma).

Comment: @Helmasan The group numbering in regex101 does not correspond to what is returned by str_match 1:1. If you run the last bit of code you will get a data frame with one column for one group so you should be able to see what goes where.

Comment: Oh, I see it. Does that mean I can apply this to anywhere where I need string (with known substring) in btw delimiters? I like tidyverse approach.

Comment: @Helmasan Yes, you can define your group as whatever is between delimiters. This may be more challenging if you have variable amount of delimiters but in general you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

If a single value without comma's on the left and right should also be valid, you can match LED between matching any char except a comma on the left and right side using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,]*`

```
[^,]*LED[^,]*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VLA6u0/1).

```
df %>% mutate(new_column = trimws(str_extract(ori_col, "[^,]*LED[^,]*")))
```

If the comma's should be present, you can use the lookarounds (note that you don't have to escape the comma's in the pattern):

```
df %>% mutate(new_column = trimws(str_extract(ori_col, "(?<=,)[^,]*LED[^,]*(?=,)")))
```

Output

```
                new_column
1                    W-LED
2 Edge LED (Local Dimming)
```

Comment: This is supposed to be done in the R language. I pretty sure that would throw an error if used as a pattern in the R regex functions.

Comment: @IRTFM You are talking about the double escaped backslash in R?

Comment: also this doesnt match OLED

Comment: @rawr Yes you are right, I removed the word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Use scan to split the strings then select based on regex logical values:

```
> inp <- scan(text=txt, what="", sep=",")
Read 9 items
> inp[ sapply( inp, function(x){grepl("LED",x)}) ]
[1] " W-LED"                    " Edge LED (Local Dimming)"
```

Comment: How do I use similar method if the string is inside a column in a data frame?

Comment: Just give the name of the string to the text= argument in scan

Answer (score 1):

Building from @rawr comment, this one works for me

```
df %>% mutate(new_column = gsub(', *([^,]*LED[^,]*),|.', '\\1', ori_col))
```

Will appreciate if someone can explain how the regex works.